# Update postmeta database for plugin in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Sorry for the stupid question, but I need to update the postmeta WordPress database for a plugin that I develop. The specific data that I want to update is: **_transaction_id**

I have searching and found a code:

```
add_post_meta($post_id, $meta_key, $meta_value, $unique);
```

But, I really don't if this work properly or how to use.

Thanks

Comment: `add_post_meta()` only adds the key if it doesn't exist. You want to use [`update_post_meta()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta) which updates and existing key *or* adds it it doesn't exist.

Comment: But it's work que line alone? Or this need to be called for a function or something else? I'm trying to do something like:

`<random_code_php>
update_post_meta(56, _transaction_id, 20020);
<random_code_php>`

This will work?

Comment: No it will not work

Comment: Use uniqid() function for random unique code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very simple. You need to use update post meta function.

```
$postid = your order id or post id.
$metakey = _transaction_id;
$metavalue = uniqid();
 update_post_meta( $postid ,'_transaction_id', uniqid());
```